# Check if NSURLCredential exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlcredential, nsurlcredentialstorage

I'm looking for a way to check if a concrete NSURLCredential is stored in my app. I'm trying to get it from NSURLCredentialStorage but I'm not founding the way to do it. Do you know if there is a way to check it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Finally, I have found a solution for this. You can get all your credentials by `[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] allCredentials]` and iterate this dictionary to found your credentials.